# Put Envelope on hold

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement to put an Envelope on hold. This is the use case:

- The system generates the documents.
- The system starts an envelope for two signers.
- Signer one signs.
- Before signer 2 signs there is a condition on the system that requires putting the envelope on hold for further verification of the documents.

Is this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as a Recipient completes/submits their documents (i.e., supplies all required data and 'Confirms Signing'), the Envelope workflow will automatically advance to the next Recipient in the routing order.  So, in the scenario you describe -- once the envelope is routed to Signer 2, there is no way to "put the envelope on hold" and temporarily prevent them from acting on it.  However, you might consider implementing something like the following approach:

1. Create the Envelope with 3 recipients in sequential order:  Routing
   order 1: **first_signer** (Signer); Routing order 2: **placeholder_recipient** (Signer recipient type -- but not an actual person -- just a fake/temp recipient that will temporarily prevent the envelope from automatically routing to **signer_2**);
   Routing order 3:  **second_signer** (Signer).
2. Once the **first_signer** completes signing, the envelope will be routed to the next recipient (**placeholder_recipient**) -- where it will remain until **placeholder_recipient** either completes signing OR until **placeholder_recipient** is deleted from the envelope.
3. Whenever it's determined either that a hold is NOT needed, or the 'further verification' is completed and the hold can be removed -- Delete **placeholder_recipient** from the envelope. As soon as you do so, the envelope will be automatically routed to the next recipient (in this example, "**signer_2**").  i.e., by simply Deleting the **placeholder_recipient**, you've essentially "removed the hold" on the envelope by allowing it to advance to the next recipient.

See pages 148-149 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for details on how to delete a recipient using the DocuSign REST API.